# How can I steal money?

Tags: hacker-experience

I have hacked into other computer and i want to steal it's money from bank and i don't know how.
  I tried to enter it's ip to "Hack Account".  But it didn't work.So what to do?

Comment: This site still has the best question titles. :)

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to hack into the bank's computer, or another person's computer. Then, you need to check their logs and hope someone accessed their bank account without cleaning the log afterwards. If they didn't clean it, there will be one or multiple bank account numbers in it.

Save the bank account numbers in notepad or something, and clean the log (so nobody else takes those numbers!). Then, hack the bank's computer and hack each account number, transfer the money and make sure to clean their log (and your log) afterwards.

This is the simplest way I know of, at least.